# How to ignore content padding/spacing between items in LazyVerticalGrid for certain items?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this design where there's a header that fills the max width with grid items underneath.

The whole screen is meant to be scrollable (the heading is meant to scroll up with the content)

So the code might look like:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(count = 2),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 24.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp) {
            item(span = {
                GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
            }) {
                Text("Heading")
            }

            items(contents) {
                Text("${it.name}")
            }
}
```

So we have a heading that fills the max span for the first item.

We also want to have a grid of items, with 24.dp between them and content padding of 16.dp horizontal and 24.dp vertical.

The issue is how since the `LazyVerticalGrid` is going to see the first heading item and apply the same padding to it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this?

You could remove those padding modifier from the `LazyVerticalGrid` and apply it to the grid items themselves, but you'll have the classic issue back with recycler views where the items double up on padding etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in many ways.

[image]

First one is changing how you measure a Composable if you don't want it to be limited by parent width - minus horizontal padding. This is also used in source code of some Composables.

```
val density = LocalDensity.current
val offsetPx = with(density) {
    16.dp.roundToPx()
}

Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val looseConstraints = constraints.offset(offsetPx * 2, 0)
            val placeable = measurable.measure(looseConstraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        }
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .border(2.dp, Color.Magenta),
    text = "Heading"
)
```

layout modifier lets you change how you measure and position a Composable. By adding 16.dp in pixel value to both sides using constraints.offset(), this is also used for creating `Padding Modifier`, You can measure with full size of parent without padding

Second way is simply using `Modifier.offset()`

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .offset((-16).dp, 0.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .border(2.dp, Color.Black),
    text = "Heading"
)
```

which is also using placeable positioning under the hood

```
private class OffsetModifier(
    val x: Dp,
    val y: Dp,
    val rtlAware: Boolean,
    inspectorInfo: InspectorInfo.() -> Unit
) : LayoutModifier, InspectorValueInfo(inspectorInfo) {
    override fun MeasureScope.measure(
        measurable: Measurable,
        constraints: Constraints
    ): MeasureResult {
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
        return layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            if (rtlAware) {
                placeable.placeRelative(x.roundToPx(), y.roundToPx())
            } else {
                placeable.place(x.roundToPx(), y.roundToPx())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3rd option would be using Modifier.graphicsLayer{}

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .graphicsLayer { 
            translationX = -16.dp.toPx()
        }
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .border(2.dp, Color.Yellow),
    text = "Heading"
)
```

And full code to try each one out. You can also create a custom layout as well.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {


        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val offsetPx = with(density) {
            16.dp.roundToPx()
        }
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, Color.Red),
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(count = 2),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 24.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp)
        ) {
            item(span = {
                GridItemSpan(

                    maxLineSpan
                )
            }) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                            val looseConstraints = constraints.offset(offsetPx * 2, 0)
                            val placeable = measurable.measure(looseConstraints)
                            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                            }
                        }
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .border(2.dp, Color.Magenta),
                    text = "Heading"
                )
            }

            item(span = {
                GridItemSpan(

                    maxLineSpan
                )
            }) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .offset((-16).dp, 0.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .border(2.dp, Color.Black),
                    text = "Heading"
                )
            }

            item(span = {
                GridItemSpan(

                    maxLineSpan
                )
            }) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .graphicsLayer {
                            translationX = -16.dp.toPx()
                        }
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .border(2.dp, Color.Yellow),
                    text = "Heading"
                )
            }

            items(10) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, Color.Green),
                    text = "Text $it"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you wonder Padding Modifier is as

```
private class PaddingModifier(
    val start: Dp = 0.dp,
    val top: Dp = 0.dp,
    val end: Dp = 0.dp,
    val bottom: Dp = 0.dp,
    val rtlAware: Boolean,
    inspectorInfo: InspectorInfo.() -> Unit
) : LayoutModifier, InspectorValueInfo(inspectorInfo) {
    init {
        require(
            (start.value >= 0f || start == Dp.Unspecified) &&
                (top.value >= 0f || top == Dp.Unspecified) &&
                (end.value >= 0f || end == Dp.Unspecified) &&
                (bottom.value >= 0f || bottom == Dp.Unspecified)
        ) {
            "Padding must be non-negative"
        }
    }

    override fun MeasureScope.measure(
        measurable: Measurable,
        constraints: Constraints
    ): MeasureResult {

        val horizontal = start.roundToPx() + end.roundToPx()
        val vertical = top.roundToPx() + bottom.roundToPx()

        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints.offset(-horizontal, -vertical))

        val width = constraints.constrainWidth(placeable.width + horizontal)
        val height = constraints.constrainHeight(placeable.height + vertical)
        return layout(width, height) {
            if (rtlAware) {
                placeable.placeRelative(start.roundToPx(), top.roundToPx())
            } else {
                placeable.place(start.roundToPx(), top.roundToPx())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using `offset` with some combination of spacers and content padding/vertical horizontal arrangements. It seems to work better than using `itemsIndexed` and applying padding to certain indices as it keeps the item sizes consistent.

Comment: Sure, you can use which one suits your requirements and preference best. First one is very useful when you don't want to constrain width after parent padding like a full width banner as first item while the rest is placed in area after padding is applied.

Comment: @Thracian what is difference between `place` and `placeRelative` ?

Comment: @VivekModi placeRelative is for right to left languages. It changes x. If you ask this as separate question i can provide a sample

Comment: Sure, I open the question. Please have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76171882/8266651).

Comment: thanks, was struggling to achieve the same. the first one worked. As far as the other two are concerned, they only seem to remove padding from the start and not the end side.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to do just that; we can't apply content padding from the LazyVerticalGrid based on the items.

The solution is to use custom padding for each item, as you said, apply some specific padding to the items themselves, and deal with the issue of double padding for each item.

One solution to deal with that is to check based on the index of the item, here is an example:

```kotlin
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(count = 2),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp)
) { items, modifier ->
    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        Text(
            text = item.toString(),
            modifier = modifier.padding(
                start = if (index % 2 == 0) 16.dp else 0.dp,
                top = if (index < 2) 0.dp else 24.dp,
                end = if (index % 2 == 1) 16.dp else 0.dp,
                bottom = if (index >= items.size - 2) 0.dp else 24.dp
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Feel fine to change the different conditions to much specific items.