# What is place vs placeRelative in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am learning the custom layout from the [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/custom). I went through the sample provide in [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/custom#create-custom) for the custom column. I see there is using `placeRelative` so what does he doing?

I was referring official video from the [Android Developer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6rAoph5UgI&t=367s). If I used `place` it working same. So what is the difference between of [`place`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/Placeable.PlacementScope#(androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable).placeRelative(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset,kotlin.Float)) and [`placeRelative`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/Placeable.PlacementScope#(androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable).placeRelative(androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntOffset,kotlin.Float))? Please provide me working example, which one should be use when.

Many Thanks

Comment: The documentation links you posted tell you the difference? `placeRelative` mirrors in RTL layouts if used in the `MeasureScope.layout` block, otherwise it acts the same as `place`. Sounds similar to `start` and `end` vs `left` and `right` in XML layout attributes, in an RTL context some things need to be flipped, so positioning depends on which side is the *start* and which is the *end*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

place

> Place a Placeable at x, y in its parent's coordinate system. Unlike
> placeRelative, the given position will not implicitly react in RTL
> layout direction contexts.

placeRelative

> Place a Placeable at x, y in its parent's coordinate system. If the
> layout direction is right-to-left, the given position will be
> horizontally mirrored so that the position of the Placeable implicitly
> reacts to RTL layout direction contexts. If this method is used
> outside the MeasureScope.layout positioning block, the automatic
> position mirroring will not happen and the Placeable will be placed at
> the given position, similar to the place method.

The difference is placeRelative mirrors x based on parent width and x position

with

```
if (parentLayoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr || parentWidth == 0) {
                placeApparentToRealOffset(position, zIndex, layerBlock)
            } else {
                placeApparentToRealOffset(
                    IntOffset((parentWidth - width - position.x), position.y),
                    zIndex,
                    layerBlock
                )
            }
```

If you create 2 Layouts with place and placeRelative with x = 50 you will get result as in image

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun SampleLayout(
    modifier: Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(content = content, modifier = modifier) { measurables, constraints ->

        val placeable = measurables.map {
            it.measure(constraints = constraints)
        }.first()

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, placeable.height) {
            placeable.place(50, 0)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SampleLayoutRTL(
    modifier: Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(content = content, modifier = modifier) { measurables, constraints ->

        val placeable = measurables.map {
            it.measure(constraints = constraints)
        }.first()

        layout(constraints.maxWidth, placeable.height) {
            placeable.placeRelative(50, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Demo

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun LayoutPlaceTest() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {

        Text(text = "LtR Language")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        SampleLayout(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(.5f)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Green)) {
            Text("place")
        }

        SampleLayoutRTL(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(.5f)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)) {
            Text("placeRelative")
        }

        Text(text = "RtL Language")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
            SampleLayout(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(.5f)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Green)) {
                Text("place")
            }

            SampleLayoutRTL(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(.5f)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red)) {
                Text("placeRelative")
            }
        }
    }
}
```